# C# create panels only in one big panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

**C# create panels only in one big panel**
I have this code (box size gets randomly generated):

```cs
//Set Location of panel
int xbox = r.Next(10, 766);
int ybox = r.Next(10, 390);
if(ybox + box.Height >= boxPanel.Location.Y + boxPanel.Height)
{
    ybox = ybox - 100;
}
else if(xbox + box.Width >= boxPanel.Location.X + boxPanel.Width)
{
    xbox = xbox - 100;
}
else if(xbox - box.Width <= boxPanel.Location.X - boxPanel.Width)
{
    xbox = xbox + 100;
}
else if (ybox - box.Height <= boxPanel.Location.Y - boxPanel.Height)
{
    ybox = ybox + 100;
}
box.Location = new Point(xbox, ybox);
```

what i want to have in the end is a box or multiple boxed which are in the panel and arent outside. I want to see the panel when i generate it. I also want to keep an "invisible" border so it does not spawn at the edge.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You might want to consider using a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-overview) anyway.

Comment: You're probably trying to add your `box` Panels to a Parent `boxPanel`. So, you're missing `boxPanel.Controls.Add(box)`. Don't consider at all the Container's Location when you define the position of the child Panels. -- If you just want random size and the position of child Controls is not relevant, use a FlowLayoutPanel as mentioned. Otherwise, just define their position / size at random and add them to the Container. `BringToFront()` can be used to show on top the last child Control added.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have `else` on those statements; they should all be separate `if` statements.  As written, if the first `y` check triggers, then none of the other blocks/checks will be run.

Why not just have the `x`, `y` values be randomly generated within the correct range in the first place?

For example:

```
// assumes "box" was already created with a desired width/height
int xbox = r.Next(10, boxPanel.Width - box.Width - 10);
int ybox = r.Next(10, boxPanel.Height - box.Height - 10);
box.Location = new Point(xbox, ybox);
boxPanel.Controls.Add(box);
```

This will keep the box within the other panel with a 10 pixel "margin" around the edges.